# Are the following modules free and/or isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

> Are the following modules $M=\mathbb{Z^3}/\langle(2,1,0),(0,-1,0)\rangle$ and $N=\mathbb{Z^3}/\langle(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\rangle$ isomorphic? Are they free? Which rank do they have?

My attempt: I would say that they are isomorphic since when i reduce the matrix made of (2,1,0), (0,-1,0) in RREF i get (1,0,0), (0,1,0), so they would span the same space? But what are elements of these two modules? And which can be a isomorphism between them? And what about their rank and fact that they're free? They are free if they have a base, but i am not sure how can I write the base in this case.

I am thankful for any sort of help or reference to literature or anything

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have serious doubts that RREF is the one you got. First of all, 2 is not invertible in the ring of integers.

You can easily get $(2,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, and then $M\simeq\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ (why?). On the other side, $N\simeq\mathbb Z$ (why?).

Comment: I am a bit unclear. You mean that I shouldn't be using RREF, right? What do you exactly mean to "get" (2,0,0) and (0,1,0)?

Comment: Yes, you can use RREF, but take care of 2. (I have added the second row to the first and then I multiplied the second row by $-1$ in order to get those two generators.)

Comment: all clear,thanks. so now would I need to find a isomorphism between them? And what about them being free?

Comment: How could find an isomorphism between them if they are isomorphic with two non-isomorphic modules, one non-free and the other one free ?

Comment: You are right, sorry. One last question, how did you know and how could I know for future use that for example by the use of RREF I had to be careful with 2.

Comment: When we are working over commutative rings which are not fields, in this case over Z, we are not allowed to multiply by "inverse" of an element which is not invertible in that ring. In our case, you can't multiply by 1/2 since this is not an element of Z.